# Paragraph element expands a div to max-width before line break

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm developing the front end for a web app in plain html and css which will be handed over for further integration.

**The Goal**

I want to create a dynamic notification element that fits the size of the paragraph until the max-width is hit and the paragraph breaks to the next line.

**The Problem**

The div is only taking on the longest words width or the min-width and not expanding fully until hitting the max-width.

I would like to keep it all in CSS but I suspect I might need some JS for this and if so, please point me in the right direction. =)

HTML

```
<div class="noti"><p>The notification text will appear over here, and spill over to the next line if long enough.</p></div>
```

CSS

```
.noti {
    height:auto;
    min-height:50px;
    width:auto;
    max-width:300px;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 55px;
    right: 0px;
    border: solid 5px #007DAC;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 5px 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#FFF;
    line-height:normal;
    text-align:left;
    color:#007DAC;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/074Lb4qb/ *EDIT* This works but the same code doesn't work in dreamweaver or previewed in firefox or chrome.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused with what the issue is after checking your jsfiddle. Are you saying the notification is becoming too small? I don't see a `min-width`

Comment: @4t0m1c Is Dreamweaver adding extra (unnecessary) code? It tends to do that... Also note that the built-in "preview option" of Dreamweaver is unreliable and doesn't always work 100% the same as it does in a real browser.

Comment: Without looking at it, it could be related to a piece of your code that is not within that jsfiddle, perhaps a universal styling on the `p` element.
It could also be related to the way dreamweaver renders a preview, although I've never used it. You can try exporting the project and see if the issue persists. If it does, it is most likely a conflicting issue within your stylesheet.

Comment: @WillThresher, so I went and uploaded it to one of my domains to test in an online environment (http://jellyterror.com/dev/Question_Interface.html) and still the same issue.. I checked the <p> styling and nothing there either.

Comment: @4t0m1c after looking at the code, it is related to the nesting of your elements. `.noti` should sit _outside_ `li.question_active`.

Comment: @WillThresher thanks, I came to the same conclusion moments before. Mega D'oh moment -_-

Comment: @4t0m1c happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks to not working modularly, I have the found the problem to be the `<li>` element that the notification `<div>` was a child of. The `<li>` element was modifying the width value.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you actually wanted to say. but you can add word-wrap: break-word;

```
.noti {
    height:auto;
    min-height:50px;
    width:auto;
    max-width:300px;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 55px;
    right: 0px;
    border: solid 5px #007DAC;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 5px 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#FFF;
    line-height:normal;
    text-align:left;
    color:#007DAC;
        word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/074Lb4qb/2/)